# Internal SD Card Reader disconnects randomly

Tags: windows-10, sd-card, card-reader

I bought a new PC (Lenovo U3170) but it seems that built-in SD card reader is broken, but I looked better, and i determined its not, because I copy pasted 1GB of files and during the transfer it was ok it took like 8 minutes...

But when not in use it keeps "crashing" like 3 in 3 minutes...

**So, what is the problem with the SD card reader?**

---

#### Edit

When not crashing if I try to open it in file explorer the pc play the "disconect" and "connect" sound (like when you Plug in a device) and it crashes too...

Comment: Did you try: different card and/or different reader with same card?

Comment: Yes. i tried other cards, which are working with another readers.

Comment: I don't understand the answer. Idea is you try determine if it's the card or the reader. So then tests could be: Does this occur with different card as well. Other test, does it occur with current card in different reader.

Comment: I want to determine what's happening with the reader. The same card works in another readers. And this issues happens with another cards too, in this reader

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after looking into the matter, it seems that windows 10 updates are the problem. So I uninstalled all updates except four updates that I could not uninstall and it works fine now.

Uninstalling the update that seems to be the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems and solved it by updating the card reader driver manually from [Realtek's Site](http://www.realtek.com.tw/Downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=15&PFid=25&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false). **BE WARNED**, your manufacturer might differ.

[image: Computer Management/Card Reader]

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to delete what I wrote and ask, did the event viewer in windows give any idea, with some error or message corresponding to the disconnect or is it just a not so silent failure ?

Originally my thought related to a hardware problem with connections vital to saying "Hey here I am, a device, communicating over this usb header HI HI HI" were not remaining intact. Like when you have a worn out USB port.

But also I seem to remember with said usb devices sometimes the device itself was the culprit, not the port. Did you try another sd card ?

Comment: This sounds very unlikely

Comment: in retrospect, yes its probably the kernel dropping the device for some reason randomly.

Comment: honestly though he said in the first x minutes the device is dropped after copying files, so if that is even linked i'm stumped as to think what physical property would cause that otherwise.

Comment: @RohitGupta but yes you're probably right I'm stupid :( and wasting my life along with everyone else responding to and asking the same things. sigh.

Comment: the guy below might have the right idea.  its mainly how does one isolate the cause of issue in this case.  if you can't debug the device driver itself because its closed source or isn't very communicative in logging error messages, can you determine if its software or hardware really ?

Comment: god i'm depressed, i made it so much further and here everyone is again and the whole world is still nuts.  and btw if after so much misery I give in and screw one of you people for being dirty dirty evil bad things when such an option is being consistently advertised I have no idea why someone would suggest that would get me dragged back to the beginning of this shit except to be an evil monster.  unrelated to the question or its responses. sigh.